# getOptions for react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

React navigation has a well documented `setOptions`. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop

However I can't seem to find any method to retrieve the current options for the active navigator. Am I missing something? Or is there a reason why it may be private?

In particular I'm interested in getting the `drawerType` option out of Drawer navigator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found these two handy methods.

```js
  nav.getCurrentOptions()
  nav.addListener('options', () => {
    
  })
```

they are both available on the `NavigationContainerRef`, which you can obtain via `createNavigationContainerRef()`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `navigationRef.getCurrentOptions`

```
// RootNavigation.js

import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef();


// App.tsx
import * as RootNavigation from './RootNavigation';
function App() {

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <NavigationContainer ref={RootNavigation.navigationRef}>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
}


// Demo.tsx
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';
function Demo() {
   const options = navigationRef.getCurrentOptions();
}
```

docs link: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/navigation-container/#getcurrentoptions